# kubernetes set root environmental variables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, kubernetes

I have a rails app that runs apache2 as root with database.yml config values set by environmental variables passed in via a kubernetes configmap.

However, since apache2 is a root process, it doesn't have the passed in environmental values. How do I set the environmental values for root from kubernetes configmap?

Comment: Please, share your Pod and ConfigMap definitions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> since apache2 is a root process, it doesn't have the passed in environmental values.

If [Use ConfigMap-defined environment variables](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/#use-configmap-defined-environment-variables-in-pod-commands) is not possible, you could [add ConfigMap data to a Volume](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/#add-configmap-data-to-a-volume), which then can be read by a wrapper to the apache2 runner.
That wrapper can:

- read the values in the config-map-based volume
- set the right environment variables
- launch Apache2